# Existence of a finite extension of ℤ providing a finite extension of the primes

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, prime-numbers, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring (possibly noncommutative with zero-divisors). A non-unit and non-zero-divisor element $r \in R$ will be called *irreducible* if for all $a,b \in R$ such that $r=ab$, then $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

Many extensions $R$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ do not keep its set of irreducible elements, for example $2 = (1+i)(1-i)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. More generally ([Chebotarev's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem)) if $R$ is the ring of integers of a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$ then the prime numbers that completely split in $R$ have density $1/n$ (so that there are infinitely many ones).

Here are examples of extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$ keeping its irreducible elements:

- $\mathbb{Z}[X]$: every prime number is an irreducible polynomial, but $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ contains also infinitely many other irreducible polynomials (up to units),
- $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Q}\epsilon$ (with $\epsilon^2=0$): it keeps the irreducibles of $\mathbb{Z}$ but there is no new ones up to units (see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271735/is-there-an-integral-extension-of-mathbbz-keeping-its-prime-elements#comment8888446_4271735)).

Observe that the extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$ mentioned above (keeping its irreducible elements) either have infinitely many new irreducible elements (up to units) or have none (up to units).

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4277145/84284) Keith Conrad provides an example with finitely many new irreducible elements (up to unit):

> Extend $\mathbf Z[x]$ by inverting all nonconstant irreducible
> elements except for $x$. That gives you a UFD whose primes elements
> are the ordinary prime numbers and $x$, up to units.

A *finite extension* of $\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring which is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ and a $\mathbb{Z}$-module of finite type. The example above is not.

**Question**: Is there a *finite* extension $R$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ keeping its irreducible elements, and also with new irreducible elements (up to units), but only finitely many (up to units)?

As Keith Conrad pointed out in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275346/existence-of-a-finite-extension-of-the-primes#comment8904743_4277145), if $R$ is an integral domain, then we are in the situation of Chebotarev's density theorem mentioned above. So $R$ must be noncommutative and/or with zero-divisors.

---

"up to units" means that if $r$ is an irreducible element and $u,v$ are units, then $r$ and $urv$ count for one.

Comment: Of course you already implicitly reference it by linking to a comment and an answer, but it may be worth mentioning that this is a refinement of an MSE question, and specifying exactly what's different from that question.

Comment: @LSpice: You are right, I will edit that later. The refinement is that it asks for a *finite* extension of $\mathbb{Z}$. Now I wonder whether the last part of the question (i.e.  "but only finitely many (up to units)") is automatic for a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: "*inverting all nonconstant irreducible elements except for* " -- ...elements in Z[x} except… ?

Comment: @WlodAA: yes, elements in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: I think the $M_n(\mathbb{Z}) $ example is flawed. The unique ring map from $\mathbb{Z} \to M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ takes $p$ to a determinant $p^n$ matrix ($p$ times the unit matrix), so the linked answer doesn't apply. And indeed, $5$ splits in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$, since $M_2$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @AchimKrause You are right! Thanks for pointed this out! It is just a morphism of monoid for the multiplication. Now note that every prime (in your sense) splits because $$\begin{bmatrix}p&0\\0&p\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}p&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&p\end{bmatrix}$$ The paragraph I wrote about $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is correct, but it is not a ring extension.

Comment: If I were you I would remove the bit about $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$, now it is really confusing to tell what you're looking for. If you're not after ring extensions and happy with some injective multiplicative monoid map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to some other ring $R$ which takes primes to irreducibles and hits all but finitely many irreducibles, you can take basically any $R$ with countably many irreducibles (for example $\mathbb{Z}$ itself).

Comment: @AchimKrause: done!

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I've now fixed all the problems I found in my answer, and it should now be complete.  There is no ring of the kind you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post started as some minor observations, but I believe it now contains a full proof that there is no such ring.  Throughout, we let $R$ be an example of the kind wanted.

**Observation 1**:  $R$ is indecomposable.

*Proof of observation 1*:  Write $R=S_1\times S_2$, with $S_1,S_2\neq 0$.  Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $S_1$ has finite characteristic $m>1$.  Let $p$ be any integer prime divisor of $m$.  Then $p=(p,p)$ is not irreducible (since $(1,0)(p,p)=0$), contradicting our assumption that the primes of $\mathbb{Z}$ stay irreducible in $R$ (and using your definition of irreducible, which includes not being a zero-divisor).

Thus, each $S_i$ has characteristic $0$.  Moreover, the argument above shows that each integer prime cannot be a zero-divisor in any $S_i$.

If an integer prime $p$ is a unit in $S_i$, then $S_i$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, which is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, contradicting the fact that submodules of finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are finitely generated.

Also, if $p$ is not irreducible in $S_1$ (or, by symmetry $S_2$), say $p=ab$ where $a,b$ are nonunits, then $(p,p)=(a,p)(b,1)$ is a product into nonunits, contradicting the irreducibility of the primes of $\mathbb{Z}$.

The elements $\{(p,1)\, :\, p>1\text{ prime}\}$ are not units, not zero-divisors, and are easily shown to be irreducible in $R$. They are not associate to each other, nor to the integer primes $(p,p)\in R$.  Thus, this would contradict our assumption of having only finitely many new primes (up to associates).

**Observation 2**: If $r\in R$, then the subring $\mathbb{Z}[r]\subseteq R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ where $I$ is a principal ideal generated by a monic polynomial $f$.

*Proof of observation 2*: Since $\mathbb{Z}[r]$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$, it must be finitely generated.  Hence, $r$ satisfies some monic polynomial.  Let $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the monic polynomial of smallest degree satisfied by $r$.

Now, $\mathbb{Z}[r]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ where $I$ is the ideal of polynomials satisfied by $r$.  It thus suffices to show that $I=f\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Supposing otherwise, let $g\in I-f\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Working over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ for a moment, take $d=\gcd(f,g)$, a monic polynomial.  Since $f$ is monic, we know that $d\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  By the extended Euclidean algorithm, we can write $d$ as a $\mathbb{Q}[x]$-linear combination of $f$ and $g$.  Hence $cd\in I$ for some minimal $c\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.  We know $c\neq 1$ by the minimality of the degree of $f$ (since $d$ is monic).

Let $p$ be any prime dividing $c$.  Then $p\cdot (c/p)d(r)=0$, and hence $p$ is a zero-divisor in $R$, which is a contradiction.

**Observation 3**: The monic polynomial $f$ is a power of an irreducible polynomial $q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

*Proof of observation 3*: Assume $f$ is not a power of an irreducible, so $f=gh$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, where $\gcd(g,h)=1$ and $\deg(g),\deg(h)\geq 1$.

By an argument used previously, we can find some constant $c\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ that is a $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-linear combination of $g$ and $h$, say $c=gg'+hh'$.

Let $J=g\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $K=h\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Let $S_1=\mathbb{Z}[x]/J$ and $S_2=\mathbb{Z}[x]/K$.  Consider the map $\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}[x]/I\to S_1\times S_2$ where $a+I\mapsto (a+J,a+K)$.  This is an injective ring homomorphism.  Thus, we can view $\mathbb{Z}[r]$ as a subring of this direct product.  Moreover the image of $\mathbb{Z}[r]$ contains the elements $(c+J,0+K)$ and $(0+J,c+K)$.  (Indeed, $h(r)h'(r)\mapsto (hh'+J,hh'+K) = (c+J,0+K)$.)  Since the image of $\mathbb{Z}[r]$ contains $(1+J,1+K)$, we see (by a trivial use of Dirichlet's theorem) that the image of $\mathbb{Z}[r]$ contains elements of the form $(p+J,1+K)$ and $(1+J,p+K)$, with $p$ an integer prime.  Thus (suppressing the coset notation) we have $(p,p)=(p,1)(1,p)$ in this image.  Back inside $\mathbb{Z}[r]$, write this factorization as $p=ab$.  Without loss of generality, $a$ is a unit in $R$, with inverse $a^{-1}$.

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[r,a^{-1}]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module (being a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$), and it naturally maps onto $(\mathbb{Z}[x]/J)[1/p]$, which is not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module, which is a contradiction.

**Observation 4**: $\deg(q)=1$.

*Proof of observation 4*: If $\deg(q)>1$, then there are infinitely many primes $p$ that factor nontrivially in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q)$ (by an argument supplied by John Voight) and such a factorization lifts to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}[r]$; see [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406752/hensels-lemma-bezouts-identity-and-the-integers) for the full argument.

Now, if such a prime $p$ is to be irreducible in $R$, one of those factors must become a unit $u$ in $R$.  But then $\mathbb{Z}[r,u^{-1}]$ is a commutative ring, mapping to $(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q))[a^{-1}]$ (where $a$ is that corresponding nontrivial factor, but modulo $q$ rather than $q^n$), which is not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module, giving us a contradiction, as before.

**Observation 5**: If $J$ is the set of nilpotent elements in $R$, then $J$ is a (nilpotent) ideal.

*Proof of observation 5*: An arbitrary element $r\in R$ satisfies $q^n$, with $q(x)=x-k\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and hence $r=k-t$ where $t$ is nilpotent of index $n$. Therefore, $r(k^{n-1}+k^{n-2}t + \cdots + t^{n-1})=k^n$.  If $k\neq 0$, then $k^n$ is not a zero-divisor (since all the primes of $\mathbb{Z}$ are not zero divisors), and hence $r$ is not a zero-divisor.  Thus, the zero-divisors are exactly the nilpotent elements.

Next, if $t\in R$ is nilpotent, say of index $n\geq 1$, and $r\in R$ is arbitrary then $t^{n-1}(tr)=0$ with $t^{n-1}\neq 0$.  Hence $tr$ is a zero-divisor, hence nilpotent.  Thus $J$ is closed by right multiplication from $R$; and by left multiplication by a symmetric argument.

In particular $J$ is closed under multiplication.  By the paper [Rings in which nilpotents form a subring](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44000112) by Janez Ster ([arXiv version here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07523)), we know that $J$ is also closed under addition, since $R$ satisfies Koethe's conjecture.  (Quick argument: The Jacobson radical $J(R)$ is nilpotent, since tensoring up to $\mathbb{Q}$ keeps it in a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.)  Thus, $J$ is an ideal.

**Observation 6**: The type of ring we want cannot exist.

*Proof of observation 6*: Fix a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $J$, say $t_1,\ldots, t_k$.  Then a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $R$ is $1,t_1,\ldots, t_k$ (since every element of $R$ is an integer shift from a nilpotent, by observation 4).

The units of $R$ are exactly $\pm 1+t$ for some $t\in J$.  Thus, the associates of a prime $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $\pm p+t'$ where $t'\in J$ is divisible by $p$.  Thus $p+t_1$ is not associate to any of the integer primes.  A similar argument shows that $p+t_1$ and $p'+t_1$ are not associate, for distinct primes $p,p'$.  Further, $p+t_1$ is not a unit, and not a nilpotent (hence not a zero-divisor).  It thus suffices to show that $p+t_1$ is irreducible, and then we'll have infinitely many "new" nonassociate irreducibles.

If $p+t_1$ factors as $(a+t)(b+t')$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $t,t'\in J$, then $ab=p$.  Hence, without loss of generality, $a=\pm 1$.  Thus, $a+t$ is a unit, so every factorization is trivial.

Comment: Dear Pace, it seems that your Observation 4 fully settles the commutative case in the negative. Doesn't it? I have two minor remarks. In the proof of Observation 1, it's not necessary to assume that an irreducible element is not a zero divisor (reasoning with $(p,1)$ and $(1,p)$ one is led to a product of fields, which contains no irreducible elements). In the proof of Observation 2, it helped me to note that $d$ is either $1$ or $f$.

Comment: @LucGuyot I figured out how to do the full case, and it is now written up.

Comment: About the proof of Observation 6: it looks as if you implicitly assumed that the additive group of $R$ is torsion-free. Can we make this assumption? A potential candidate is the Nagata idealization $\mathbb{Z} (+) \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. It fails to match the requirements only because $(2^n, 1 + 2 \mathbb{Z})$ is irreducible for every $n > 0$. (By the way, isn't $d$ necessarily equal to $1$ in the proof of Observation 2?)

Comment: @LucGuyot The primes of $\mathbb{Z}$ remain irreducible, and according to the given definition irreducibles must not be zero-divisors.  Thus, the additive group of $R$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Thanks, I feel ashamed, as I should have remembered it!  I also acknowledge that my question/remark about $d$ was non-sensical: I see that $d \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ simply because of Gauss's lemma. Your answer looks complete and great to me.

Comment: @PaceNielsen What is your easiest example if we remove "but only finitely many (up to units)" in the question?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux I'd say $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$ is probably the easiest such example.

Comment: @PaceNielsen: Yes sure, I was confused by the example $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Q}\epsilon$ (with $\epsilon^2=0$) which keeps the prime numbers as prime elements, whereas $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\epsilon$ keeps them as irreducible elements only (not prime, because every $p$ divides $\epsilon^2 = 0$ but does not divide $\epsilon$).